# Swagger Failing Authorization: Bearer [object Object] nestJS

Tags: swagger, nestjs, swagger-ui

Swagger on local works fine and send a correct Authorization token
Deploying on Dev environment with same configuration cause this.

Authorization: Bearer [object Object]

its converting JWT token to [object Object] it was working perfectly a couple of days ago with the same modules

"swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0",
"@nestjs/swagger": "^5.2.0"

Answer (score 0):

This [was a bug](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/7926) introduced in Swagger UI v. 4.7.0. It was fixed in Swagger UI v. 4.8.1.

Update your packages to the versions that include Swagger UI v. 4.8.1.